# AppDomain dynamic assembly loading for ASP.NET MVC on Windows Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, appdomain, .net-assembly

I have already several .NET **backgrounds apps** on Windows Azure (aka Worker Roles) that are relying on AppDomain isolation and dynamic assembly loading. The main benefits are:

- rebooting the app with new assemblies takes a few seconds (versus 5min for VM reboot).
- teamwork is simplified as we can use the Azure Storage account to grant narrow access to the app only (instead of granting accesses to all Windows Azure services through the portal).

I am currently considering extending the process to Web Role for **ASP.NET MVC** webapp. Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Do you really need to do anything?  Just copying a new assembly into the bin folder should force the app to restart.  Or are you somehow re-hosting MVC outside of IIS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already doing dynamic loading in a worker role then why the question for a web role. It is exactly the same.

Maybe you can elaborate a little on what you thing you are missing?